# Characteristic classes of invariant star products

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, characteristic-classes

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ a Lie algebra, can one compute the $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant Deligne class of an invariant star product by using some kind of invariant local $\nu$-Euler derivation?